# How can I organize my routes better in nodejs & express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

My WebAPI code at the moment is pretty modular I would say. But I would like it to be even more.

I have this server.js file that has all the routes, and I would like to split them into separate controllers. Any idea on how to do that? Here's an example:

```
app.get('/users/me', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

I have a bunch of these routes in my server.js file. How would I go about creating a user-routes.js file with my user routes there? Also for all the other collections' routes I have set up.

```
app.post('/firm', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    var firm = new Firm({
        name: req.body.name,
        number: req.body.number,
        _creator: req.user._id
    });

    Firm.findOne({
        number: req.body.number,
        _creator: req.user._id
    }).then(firmFound => {
        if (firmFound) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Firm with that name or number already exists.'
            })
        }
        firm.save().then((firm) => {
            res.send(firm);
        }, (e) => {
            res.status(400).send(e);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Mongodbs `findOneAndUpdate` might be your friend for `/firm`

Comment: That route is for creating a new firm. with findOne() I am checking if there is a Firm with that number, and if there is I am throwing status(400), and if there's not I proceed to save the document. I'm still pretty new to mongoose so I might be wrong! How would findOneAndUpdate be useful here?

Comment: Oh never mind, did not see that this is mongoose. The code is fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a subfile, e.g. `users.js` you can define a new `Router`:

```
const users = Express.Router();

users.get("/me", () => "whatever");

module.exports = users;
```

That applies to all your subroutes and even subsubroutes. 
Then on the higher instance you just need to mount that subroutes under their path (server.js for example):

```
app.use("/users/", require("users.js"));
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for :)

Comment: @filip glad to help ;)